# PDO Compare two Arrays with different formats

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have two arrays: 
$teachArray that has been populated through a Form. 
$learnArray that is the result of a PDO Select query.

I want to compare $teachArray to $learnArray using array_diff() function in order to insert new data into my database.

I don't know how to correctly transform $learnArray into the same format as $teachArray.

When I print_r($teachArray) I get the result: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
When I print_r($learnArray), I get the result: Array ( [0] => Array ( [language_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [language_id] => 2 ))

```
if(isset($_POST['teach']))
        {
            $teachArray = $_POST['teach'];

            $sqlGet = "SELECT language_id FROM language_skill WHERE person_id = :person_id AND language_learning = :language_learning";
            $query = $handler->prepare($sqlGet);
            $query->bindValue(':person_id', $_SESSION['person_id']);
            $query->bindValue(':language_learning', 1);
            $query->execute();
            $number_of_rows = $query->rowCount();
            $learnArray = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); **// How do I correctly fetch it.**

            $sqlInsertTeach = "INSERT INTO language_skill (person_id, language_id, language_learning, language_teaching)
                               VALUES(:person_id, :language_id, :language_learning, :language_teaching)";

            if ($number_of_rows > 0) {
                $differentLanguageChosen = array_diff($teachArray, $learnArray);
                foreach ($differentLanguageChosen as $dataTeach) {
                    $query = $handler->prepare($sqlInsertTeach);
                    $query->bindValue(':person_id', $_SESSION['person_id']);
                    $query->bindValue(':language_id', $dataTeach);
                    $query->bindValue(':language_learning', 0);
                    $query->bindValue(':language_teaching', 1);
                    $query->execute();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$learnArray = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

with

```
$learnArray = [];
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $learnArray[] = $row['language_id'];
}
```

Or even simplier:

```
$learnArray = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

where `0` is an index of a column you want to fetch. As you have `language_id` column only - it's index is 0.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful